# How to configure the popular TAGS block

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I need this effect, but I don't know how to do that:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I am sorry, but _I need to implement this as you see in the screenshot_ questions are expressly off-topic for us, as per Help Center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello You can use Tag Cloud Module for this purpose it is easy to use, following is simple method to show Popular Tags block

1. Unzip and copy the directory to `/sites/all/modules`.
2. `/admin/modules` activate **TagClouds**.
3. `/admin/config/content/tagclouds` set the Settings to what you want. See **Module Settings** bellow.
4. `/admin/structure/block` and find the block titled "Tags in [taxonomy name]" and move to where you want it displayed. See "Block Settings" bellow.

Your all set up!

Best Wishes 
Rana

Answer (score 1):

[cctags](https://www.drupal.org/project/cctags)

> flexible configuration and advanced features for theming clouds.
>   (individual files of templates for tags, the names of the dictionary, pages clouds)
>
> Possibility (in settings include several dictionaries (as for
>   dictionaries with tree structure - in addition to enable / disable the
>   desired level)) tags. Automatic generation of the required number of
>   blocks and / or pages. Generation unit of Tag attached to the node.
>   Generation of block-related materials for the node (via tags) Cloud
>   members users (block and page) (with weights proportional to the
>   number of published material)

[TagCloud](https://www.drupal.org/project/tagclouds)

> Tag clouds is a light weight stable module that provides span tags,
>   optimizations; It is also singular in purpose and stable.
>
> Provides a link to the node and not the taxonomy display if the node
>   count is equal to 1. This avoids taxonomy pages with only one node.
>   Defaults to On, can be turned off

OR you can do it

You can do this with views:

- create a view of terms
- add a required relationship to "content using tags"
- set use aggregation: yes
- add the "term name" field a second time, set one of the to
  "aggregation type: count"
- add "term name" as a sort criteria, set "aggregation type: count"

Answer (score 0):

There are certain modules that will do this.

**[TagCloud](https://www.drupal.org/project/tagclouds)**

> This module Provides a TagCloud and List of Tags.
>   Tag clouds is a light weight stable module that provides span tags,
>   optimizations; It is also singular in purpose and stable.

**[Tagadelic](https://www.drupal.org/project/tagadelic)**

> Tagadelic provides an API and a few simple turnkey modules, which
>   allows you to easily create tagclouds, weighted lists, search-clouds
>   and such.
>   With the API you can build a module with a few lines of PHP, to turn
>   anything that can be counted into a weighted cloud. Which can be
>   presented to your users anyway and anywhere on your site.

**[cctags](https://www.drupal.org/project/cctags)**

> module cctags - as an alternative to module tagadelic.
>   flexible configuration and advanced features for theming clouds.
>   (individual files of templates for tags, the names of the dictionary,
>   pages clouds)

and with effects
**[Cumulus](https://www.drupal.org/project/cumulus)**

> Cumulus allows you to display your site's tags using Flash that
>   rotates them beautifully in 3D. It works like a regular tag cloud, but
>   is more visually exciting.